# "Extract by Mask" saving output as temporary file, instead of saving it in specific directory. How to remove this error?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst

I am using ArcGIS 10.0, while using `ExtractByMask` in `arcpy` output file is being stored as a temporary file, though the same file appears in the designated directory but it's status is temporary, which doesn't open up once we close the ArcMap.

Here is my script

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *


shape="G:/Path/To/Shapefile.shp"
raster="G:/Path/To/In_Raster.tif"
output="G:/Path/To/Out_Raster.tif"

out= ExtractByMask(raster, shape)
out.save(output)
```

How to save output in desired directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending enough time, I found that this is the problem with ArcGIS 10.0.
I installed ArcGIS 10.1 and the script worked fine.